# Keyboard shortcuts: show already open window instead of opening new one

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have the keybinding Super + T assigned to Terminal. So, if I press the key binding, Terminal will open. But if it's already open, it will create a new tab and focus on it.

Is there a proper way to assign a shortcut to *show that already open window and focus on it* instead of *create a new instace of that window*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Reddit user suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/89npjj/keyboard_shortcuts_show_already_open_window/), one useful solution is to use [Jumpapp](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp).